# Convert HTML colour to grayscale

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to convert the following HTML colours to their greyscale counterpart?

```
table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 { background-color: #D3D6FF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_2 { background-color: #DADCFF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_3 { background-color: #E0E2FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 { background-color: #EAEBFF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_2 { background-color: #F2F3FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_3 { background-color: #F9F9FF; }
```

e.g.

```
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }
```

would become

```
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: black; }
```

Comment: There's no way to achieve that with pure CSS. You can look at using the `desaturate()` function of LESS > http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Oh, by the way, the example you gave isn't great - white is already a component of greyscale, so I don't quite understand why it should become black?

Comment: @BenM I think he wants the complementary colour.